# Azure Site Recovery unplanned failover

Tags: azure, failover

I have managed to create a DR of a couple virtual machines to Azure. I am using Azure site recovery and Azure resource manager, and I followed this manual about how to do this https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/azure-azure-site-recovery-with-arm-replication-and-failover-failback.

When I was doing unplanned failover of the virtual machine, it said that unplanned failover failed. Error id is 70136:

> Possible causes The operation was cancelled or the recovery
>   point is not available for failover.  Recommendation Wait for a while
>   and retry the operation.

I try to search the solution, but not successful. Any solution? P.S. sorry for my not good English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of technet threads about this, [one of them](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0ed854be-b7c5-40a1-ae2c-e5f23a54329d/failover-test-and-unpland-failover-error-id-70136-and-id-539?forum=hypervrecovmgr) for example. I'd suggest you to collect the logs and contact Azure support, or, at least ask for the status of this thread.

UPD: just ran through this guide, and the failover runs smooth. I guess, it is a specific error related to your configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to reinstall this configuration from the begin, and it is working now. If it will be a problem again, I will try to submit a question to Azure support.